# Is this function strongly convex?

Tags: calculus, continuity, convex-analysis

Let $A,B$ be two intervals in $\mathbb R$ and let $f:A\times B\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function.

Assume that $f$ is convex in both $x$ and $y$.

Is the following function $g:A \to \mathbb R$  strongly convex w.r.t. the Euclidian norm?

$$g(x):=\int _{B} |f(x,y)-f(x_1,y)|^2dy.$$

Comment: what about $f(x,y) = x^2-1$ for $A= [-1,1]$ and $x_1 = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

@user251257 is correct: the function $f \colon [- 1, 1] \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$, $(x, y) \mapsto x^2$ is convex in both arguments and continuous.
Let $x_1 \in [- 1, 1]$.
Then
\begin{equation*}
g(x)
= \int_{0}^{1} | x^2 - x_1^2 |^2 \, \text{d}y
= (x^2 - x_1^2)^2
\end{equation*}
is not strongly convex: for $x \in [-1, 1]$ we have
$$
\nabla^2 g(x)
= 12 x^2 - 4 x_1^2
$$
and for e.g. $x = 0$ and $x_1 \ne 0$ this is negative.